# Collection is not a fuction Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried to get my bot to fetch other Javascript files but it says that `Collection is not a function`

```
client.command = Client.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
    } else if (command === 'ping'){
        client.command.get('ping').execute(message,args);
    }
```

The code is bigger but I removed it so it doesn't take up so much space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection` is a class which should be invoked once required from the library

```js
const { Collection } = require('discord.js');

client.commands = new Collection();
```

Comment: Thanks my dude for the help ( now I have other problem but I going to discover how to fix) [ReferenceError: Cannot access 'client' before initialization]

Comment: That's unrelated to your post. If this answer solved your first problem click the check mark to the left and consider posting a new question on your new error